# Instana integration with create-react-app to download sourcemap for error reporting

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, source-maps, error-reporting, instana

The source map for CRA is enabled by default. I have given Instana the permission to download source map from my application in production, but the errors reported are still compressed and uglified. I guess the configuration has no effect.

Referring to [this doc](https://docs.instana.io/products/website_monitoring/faq/#what-is-javascript-stack-trace-translation).

When I do a curl for the source map from the terminal, it works.
My site is on HTTPS, but the doc says it makes an HTTP request. 
Is that the root cause? How to fix it?

```
//Curl
curl 'https://{my url}/static/js/{sourcemap name}.map' -H  
'cache-control: no-cache' -H 
'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
```

Answer (score 2):

Instana will use the same protocol to make the sourcemap request. The documentation example uses http, but it will work with https the same way. 
The most likely reason for your problem is that the sourcemap is not readable from the public internet. In your case, the sourcemap file requires http session authentication and redirects to a login page.

Comment: What kind of response to you receive when making the curl request? I would guess that it is not the JavaScript file content, but instead maybe an HTTP redirect or a sign in page?